# Opening a new pop up window when a menu click

Tags: php, html, popupwindow

How can I make my menu that when clicks it gonna open a new window or a pop up window?

this is my menu code:

```
<?php foreach ($_SESSION["access"] as $key => $access) { ?>
   <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span><?php echo $access["top_menu_name"]; ?></span></a>
        <ul>
            <li><span><?php
                        foreach ($access as $k => $val) {
                            if ($k != "top_menu_name") {
                                echo '<li><a href="'.$val["page_name"].'" ><i class="fa fa-forward"></i> ' . $val["menu_name"] . '</a></li>';
                                ?>
                                <?php
                            }
                        }
                        ?></span></li>

        </ul>   
   </li>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: You need to to this by JavaScript

Comment: https://codingtips.kanishkkunal.in/open-links-popup/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use 'target="_blank"', or did i misunderstood the question?

Answer (score 0):

use "window.open" using javascript or like call below function on your anchor tag click.

set file path to myFIle variable.

function mypopup() {

```
var myFile = 'your_file_path';
var myName = 'Windhow Heading'
var image = window.open(myFile, '', "left=0,top=0,width=900,height=600,status=no,toolbar=no,directories=no,scrollbars=yes,location=no,resizable=no,menubar=no");
return false;
```

}